# Why can't `{ a: string }` flow into `{ a?: string }`

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Given object type `A` and `B` where both are the same except that `A`'s properties are optional… why can't be `B` used in place where `A` is accepted?

```
type A = { a?: string };
type B = { a: string };

const x: B = { a:'…' };

// …string is incompatible with undefined in property `a`
(x: A)
```

[Flow try link here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN5gCGA-AFxgDOGATgJYB2A5mAL4DcmXAQBCpCtQbN23PoNQBjOB2ZgAHgzFlKVOgHJAZAR65qABQaiASiA)

Comment: Replacing your last line with `function foo(foo: A) {} foo(x);` works fine on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @JonasBerlin What I've posted is the minimal repro of the same thing you are trying to do in your example, so it can't really work either (as can be seen on flow try: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN5gCGA-AFxgDOGATgJYB2A5mAL4DcmXAQBCpCtQbN23PoNQBjOB2ZgAHgzFlKVOgHJAZAR65qABQaiASlRQArhwUY2ysFDhxTbuA0KWKvG3dzS34gA])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Flow is trying to warn that if `x` gets typed as an `A` then it could potentially be modified such that it still fulfills the type definition of `A` but does not fulfill the type definition of `B`. For example, you could delete the `a` property if `x: A`, which would violate `B`.

I tested this by creating a new "read only" version of `A` and casting `x` to it.

```
type Required = { a: string};
type Optional = { a?: string };
type ReadOnlyOptional = $ReadOnly<Optional>;

const x: Required = { a: '' };
(x: Optional); // error
(x: ReadOnlyOptional); // no error!
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXAlgJwgEygXigbygEMAuKAZ2FWQDsBzAXwG4AoUSKAeTGGQHtrCAGxz4iAflIUqdKE1bhocQhg7VBILj35CRAEiUq1IADya+AwQD4WzAMb8KUAB6k4SNJhEESUAOS-ZFgAKF05ucyEASmDQg1V1M21BaKA)

Comment: All that time I've been using this thing and still it hurts my brain when I bump into these things (`variance` itself is a chapter for itself…).

Thanks for you input. It did finally click for me…

Now I just don't know what I'll do since the `Optional` variant is accepted by external library and I have a global type where:
 - I do ensure the the property is there (hence I can safely do string manipulation on)
 - I want it to be accepted by that library.

Ovewriting the lib's typedef is a fugly solution… oh my…

Comment: Be careful of changing the lib's typedef in case the library really does modify its arguments. If it doesn't, then the [`$ReadOnly` utility type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-readonly) should definitely be used.

Comment: Yep … that is part of the funkiness of that "solution"

Answer (score 0):

For be able to perform a type casting the type to be cast to must be included in the type definition of the current type.

In this case

```
type A = { a?: string };
type B = { a: string };
```

It is impossible to cast these types, neither A > B nor B > A, because its type definition does not match.

If you defined the next types:

```
type A = { a?: string };
type B = { a?: string, b: number };
```

you can cast from type B to Type A

```
const x: B = { a: '...', b: 1 };
(x: A)

const x: B = { b: 1 };
(x: A)
```

these are valid ones, due to type A is included in type B.

But you cannot cast from type A to type B due to type A definition is not included in type B.

```
const x: A = { a: '...' };
(x: B)
```

this cast fails.