# Manipulate list of Flow generic type with optional id

Tags: flowtype

I'd like to have a function that takes an array with objects that could have `id` property on them. The function will remove the first object that has `id` and it matches function's second argument.

Here is my stub:

```js
// @flow

function removeFromArrayByObjectId<T: {id?: string}>(array: Array<T>, id: any): Array<T> {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].id && array[i].id === id) { 
      array.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

export {
  removeFromArrayByObjectId,
};
```

When I'm passing `arr` defined as (below) I'm getting

```js
type Obj = { id: string, value: string };
const arr: Array<Obj> = [obj1, obj2];
```

> Cannot call `removeFromArrayByObjectId` with array literal bound to `array` because  string [1] is incompatible with  undefined [2] in property `id` of array element.Flow(InferError)

However, when I remove `?` from `id?` it works fine. I'm expecting that some arrays will have elements without the `id` so would like it to be optional. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very similar to the one mentioned in [Why can't `{ a: string }` flow into `{ a?: string }`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57255895/why-cant-a-string-flow-into-a-string/57256376#57256376). Essentially, Flow does not know that `removeFromArrayByObjectId` does not manipulate the elements of `array` (e.g., delete a property). You'll want to mark `T` as "read-only" so Flow knows that the function will not do so.

```
function removeFromArrayByObjectId<T: $ReadOnly<{id?: string}>>(array: Array<T>, id: any): Array<T> {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].id && array[i].id === id) { 
      array.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

type Obj = { id: string, value: string };
declare var obj1: Obj;
declare var obj2: Obj;
const arr: Array<Obj> = [obj1, obj2];
const modified_arr: Array<Obj> = removeFromArrayByObjectId(arr);
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYFs4DdUDFlzoCCyyAhgJ4BCFA8gEYBWq0AkgCYA8AKgFyIASAEqoy7WmAA2FTgG8Y7APz8AzlGQwwAcwC+APj0AKMqUr8S5Gdz0AaRAv5kwFAJTnTVvYlkAoRImA4ZERDSVQoe0QAXkQABgBuSM5EE0sAOjDtKAALRJgAanyXbz9-e2AQ1MoAbRgAXTSFRAAyZpSPWoamqJ77dmLZRFKy9vSVAAdJGAhUQxg7AEYXeOGy+jQyAGsVkZ1Svf80KBBkJCqKFYOR65vbu7ufKApx1EQGRmjvPtV1TS07LBkSQgVA-DTaRA6FbsFiSEyvQHBOBMBb8d7Q2HwxCIxDIxgAJjRTBWEAQalG7ksnHeXhi1TxCzsePxdRJZIimHYMGAMFQ7AA+qlKZRqUxaSgMNg8ARiB4aO8WFAOMZSMsfEA)

Comment: Yep, works. Thought better of Flow but this isn't that bad.